# Second iteration in XML reading with Linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, linq

I have a webservice running in C#, which communicates to an external party with XML-files. All works great, but now I need to scan a XML-file which has 2 elements that I need to iterate over.
The XML has the same layout as the one below.

```
<Order>
    <OrderLine>
        <OrderID>5</OrderID>
        <Description>OrderDescription</Description>
        <Value>150</Value>
        <Option>
            <OptionID>15</OptionID>
            <OptionDescription>OptionDescription</OptionDescription>
        </Option>
        <Option>
            <OptionID>16</OptionID>
            <OptionDescription>Another Option</OptionDescription>
        </Option>
    <OrderLine>
    <OrderLine>
        <OrderID>5</OrderID>
        <Description>OrderDescription</Description>
        <Value>150</Value>
        <Option>
            <OptionID>5</OptionID>
            <OptionDescription>OptionDescription</OptionDescription>
        </Option>
    <OrderLine>
</Order>
```

In the webservice I iterate over every OrderLine element within the Order parent. Works as it should.

The problem however lays in the Option-elements within the OrderLine.
The amount of Option-elements is not static. Per OrderLine it can vary.
So I though I'd use the same method as I use for the OrderLines.
However I get an expection when I do this.

```
 Object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

I narrowed the exception down to the problem. And it lays in this line.

```
Options = (from option in lines.Elements("Option")
           where option.HasElements
           select new Option() {
               OptionId = option.Element("OptionID").Value,
               Description = option.Element("OptionDescription").Value
           }).ToList()
```

Options is a IEnumerable with Option as its class. The Option class has 2 variables, OptionID and Description.
Any thoughts on how to correctly reference the object?

Comment: Which object is `null`?

Comment: @eddie_cat The Options object in the line of code. It doesn't get any value, while I don't see a fault in the query

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't it be:

```
option.Element("OptionDescription").Value
```

and not:

```
option.Element("Description").Value
```

Comment: Good point. Made a mistake while typing this. But it's all correct in the code. And if this was indeed the mistake, wouldn't the description alone be empty instead of the Options object?

Comment: @RobvanBarneveld I thought that maybe the typing error led to option.Element("Description") returning null and then when you try to get the Value property from it, a null reference exception is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

What is stored in lines?

Check to see that option and lines are not null.